# How to repeat random walk simulation and record end results in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, random-walk

Hi I am working on my first random walk program. I was just able to figure out the random walk program itself. It is a simple 1d random walk, with 1000 steps. Here is what my code looks like so far:

```
stepslim = 1000;
rnew(1) = 0
r=0;
%Now we will set up the for loop
for isteps = 2:1:stepslim;
    if rand <= 0.5             %The if-else statement will tell the walker
        step = -1;             %which direction it steps in
    else
        step = +1;
    end
    rnew(isteps) = rnew(isteps-1) + step; %This adds the new step
end
plot(rnew); %This will plot our random walk
```

This works just fine, and now I need to attempt a few more tasks:

- Run this simulation X times to generate an ensemble.  Record/store the final location of the walker at the end of each simulation in the ensemble.
- Generate a histogram for the ending position of the walker for each simulation in the ensemble ▪ Adjust the bin-width to “make sense” of your results.
- Repeat and plot results for X = [1000,  2000,  10000,  20000,  100000,  1000000]

I am not sure how to repeat the simulation and record the ending values into an ensemble. I would appreciate some help in accomplishing these tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method for generating the random walks is very, very, very slow... if you want to change your approach, I would suggest you yo use the following code instead:

```
steps = 1000;
rw = cumsum(-1 + 2 * round(rand(steps,1)),1);
```

Starting from that point, here is how you could run your simulation `x` times, record each result and retrieve the last step of every simulation:

```
iters = 10;
steps = 1000;

rws = NaN(steps,iters);

for i = 1:iters
    rws(:,i) = cumsum(-1 + 2 * round(rand(steps,1)),1);
end

% retrieve the last step
last_steps = rws(end,:);
```

In order to plot an histogram of the last steps, you could use the `histogram` function which should be flexible enough to print something coherent enough with your data:

```
histogram(last_steps);
```

To use different step sizes, just enclose everything inside another `for loop` in which you cycle on every step size that you define within an array:

```
X = [1000, 2000, 10000, 20000, 100000, 1000000];

for j = 1:numel(X)
    % previous code with variable "steps" replaced by X(j)
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Would you mind explaining the first four lines of your second code? I am a little confused on what "iters" and "rws_off" are.

Comment: Well... in the first two I declare the parameters of the process: how many for-loops iterations and how many random walk steps. The third one is a variable in which I store my results (I declare it before proceeding with a dummy value because of performance reasons) and the fourth line was an unnecessary leftover.